# MongoDB Authentication Failed only from remote connections

Tags: mongodb, authentication, local

If I login over the mongo shell from local, all works fine but if I try to login with a remote connection it says "Authentication failed". I tried it with the programs "MongoClient", "RoboMongo" and "MongoManagement Studio".

I despair because I dont know what I can do...

Comment: You're talking about a same mongo instance or multiple instances in different machines? The last time that happened to me it was due to two machines having different versions. One was 3.2, the other one was an old 2.6.6.

Comment: @TanKimLoong No, i have the Version 3.2.8 on the DB Server and version 1.2.1 of MongoClient wich will work with MongoDB 3.2.8